# Getting " wrong argument type Fixnum (expected String) (TypeError)" while running the Cucumber tests whenever it encounters the Capybara function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, phantomjs, cucumber, capybara

I am trying to use capybara in my feature tests, but I keep getting the above error. However, my tests work when non Capybara functions are involved.

Here is the settings in my env.rb:

```
    Capybara.server_host = 45454
    #Capybara.server_host = host
    Capybara.app_host = 'http://localhost:45454'
    Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
```

PATH variable is also set for Phantomjs

Following is the steps definition file where I am facing the issue.

```
   Given(/^I navigate to home page$/) do 
     visit '/'
   end

  And /^I take screenshot$/ do
    page.save_screenshot
  end
```

Following is the feature file

```
 Scenario: To validate the page shows up
   Given I navigate to home page
     And I take screenshot
```

Here is the output:

```
 Scenario: To validate the page shows up←[90m # features/home.feature:8←[0m
 ←[31mGiven I navigate to home page←[90m         # features/step_definitions/
 home_steps.rb:8←[0m←[0m
 ←[31m      wrong argument type Fixnum (expected String) (TypeError)←[0m
 ←[31m      ./features/step_definitions/home_steps.rb:9:in `/^I navigate to 
 home
 page$/'←[0m
 ←[31m      features/home.feature:9:in `Given I navigate to home page'←[0m
 ←[36mAnd I take screenshot←[90m                 # features/step_definitions/
  home_steps.rb:12←[0m←[0m
 ←[31m      wrong argument type Fixnum (expected String) (TypeError)←[0m

 ←[31mFailing Scenarios:←[0m
  ←[31mcucumber features/home.feature:8←[0m←[90m # Scenario: To validate the 
 page
 shows up←[0m

 1 scenario (←[31m1 failed←[0m)
 2 steps (←[31m1 failed←[0m, ←[36m1 skipped←[0m)
  0m0.649s
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but having a `server_host` containing an integer seems suspicious. Also, note that "I take screenshot" is not a user action and doesn't really fit in a scenario.

Comment: Agreed, it was just to for debug purpose. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Capybara.server_host` needs to be the hostname/ip of an interface Capybara can bind the AUT to, not a number.

You're probably trying to set the port, which would be

```
Capybara.server_port = 45454
```

and then judging by your setting of `app_host` (which probably isn't necessary) you also want to be setting

```
Capybara.server_host = 'localhost'
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that was exactly the problem.

Comment: @Vaibhav You're welcome, don't forget to accept the answer (the checkmark) if there's nothing more you need,  so your question gets marked as answered.